# Did the Prophet (SAW) not see Allah during the night of ascension?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, allah, hadith-interpretation, miraj

I ask this question due to this Hadith from Sahih Musllim:

It is narrated on the authority of Masruq that he said:

> I was resting at (the house of) 'A'isha that she said:
>  O Abu 'A'isha
>   (kunya of Masruq), there are three things, and he who affirmed even
>   one of them fabricated the greatest lie against Allah.
>  I asked that
>   they were.
>  She said: **He who presumed that Muhammad (ﷺ) saw his Lord
>   (with his ocular vision) fabricated the greatest lie against Allah.** 
> I
>   was reclining but then sat up and said:
>  Mother of the Faithful, wait a
>   bit and do not be in a haste. Has not Allah (Mighty and Majestic)
>   said:" And truly he saw him on the clear horizon" ([Al-Qur'an, Surat
>   at-Takwir, 81:23](https://quran.com/81/23)) and" he saw Him in another descent" ([Al-Qur'an,
>   Surat Najm 53:13](https://quran.com/53/13))?
>  She said: I am the first of this Ummah who asked
>   the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) about it, and he said:
>  Verily he is
>   Gabriel. I have never seen him in his original form in which he was
>   created except on those two occasions (to which these verses refer); I
>   saw him descending from the heaven and filling (the space) from the
>   sky to the earth with the greatness of his bodily structure.
>  She said:
>   Have you not heard Allah saying:
>  "Eyes comprehend Him not, but He
>   comprehends (all) vision. and He is Subtle, and All-Aware" ([Al-Qur'an,
>   Surat al-An`am 6:103](https://quran.com/6/103))? 
> (She, i.e. 'A'isha, further said): 
> Have you not
>   heard that, verily, Allah says:
>  "And it is not for any human being
>   that Allah should speak to him except by revelation or from behind a
>   partition or that He sends a messenger to reveal, by His permission,
>   what He wills. Indeed, He is Most High and Wise." ([Al-Qur'an, Surat
>   ash-Shura, 42:51](https://quran.com/42/51)) 
>   She said: He who presumes that the Messenger of
>   Allah (ﷺ) concealed anything from the Book of Allah fabricates the
>   greatest lie against Allah.
>  Allah says: "O Messenger, announce that
>   which has been revealed to you from your Lord, and if you do not, then
>   you have not conveyed His message. And Allah will protect you from the
>   people. Indeed, Allah does not guide the disbelieving people."
>   ([Al-Qur'an, Surat al-Ma'idah, 5:67](https://quran.com/5/67)). 
> She said: He who presumes that he
>   would inform about what was going to happen tomorrow fabricates the
>   greatest lie against Allah. 
> And Allah says "Say, 'None in the heavens
>   and earth knows the unseen except Allah , and they do not perceive
>   when they will be resurrected.'" [(Al-Qur'an, Surat an-Naml, 27:65](https://quran.com/27/65)).
>
> [Sahih Muslim -  Book 1, Hadith 346](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/1/346)

Comment: Isn’t there a famous Hadith where the Sahaba ask the Prophet PBUH and he replies by saying how could he see Allah when Allah is engulfed with light?

Comment: @Shadi Unfortunately, I haven't come across it. If you have it handy, will you share me the link please.

Comment: It was narrated that Abu Dharr said:”I asked the Messenger of Allah PBUH, “Did you see your Lord?” He said “He is veiled by light, how could I see Him?” (Narrated by Muslim, al-Eeman, 261)

Comment: Jazakallah Khair (https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/1/350)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment by @Shadi above:

> It is narrated on the authority of Abu Dharr:
>
> I asked the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ): Did you see thy Lord? He said: **(He
> is) Light; how could I see Him?**
>
> [Sahih Muslim, Book 1, Hadith 350](https://sunnah.com/muslim:178a)